# One Case I came through while parsing my XML file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

So my XML file goes somewhat like this:

```
<Root>
  <S_CellBody Id = "16393">
   <?OldID 16393?>
   <ph Id = "19393">SELx</ph>
    (x=0)
  </S_CellBody>
</Root>
```

I want to extract (x=0) form this XML using ElementTree Library in python
I am trying to access it using my below code:

(say I read this XML from a file in a variable 'tree')
Python 3.5 code:

```
root= tree.getroot()
s_cellbody= root.find('.//S_CellBody').text
print(s_cellbody)
```

But this above code gives me the output 'None'

I don't understand what is happening coz '(x=0)' is the text under the tag 'S_CellBody'. Can anyone explain this!!!!

EDIT1: S_cellBody was just a typo! sorry I have corrected it to 'S_CellBody'

Comment: The text you are looking for is the `tail` of the `<ph>` element. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail.

Comment: Thank you @mzjn this what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take the tail of that element.

Please check the code from ipython console below,

```
In [1]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

In [2]: cat myxml.xml
<Root>
  <S_CellBody Id = "16393">
   <?OldID 16393?>
   <ph Id = "19393">SELx</ph>
    (x=0)
  </S_CellBody>
</Root>

In [3]: tree = ET.parse('myxml.xml')

In [4]: root = tree.getroot()

In [5]: elem = root.find('S_CellBody')

In [6]: if elem:
   ...:     print(elem[0].tail)
   ...:     
/usr/local/bin/ipython:1: FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions.  Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.
  #!/usr/bin/python

    (x=0)


In [7]: if elem is not None:
   ...:     print(elem[0].tail)
   ...:     

    (x=0)
```

Comment: Instead of "the tail of that element", it is better to write "the tail of the `<ph>` element".